# Wordpress browse by taxonomy returns 404

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, taxonomy, custom-post-type

I have looked all over and have been at this for about a week now. If anyone could help it'd be greatly appreciated.

I'm making an online weekly newspaper. The paper has a new Issue every week and they belong to a volume which increments each year.

I have a custom taxonomy Issue with parent term Volume and multiple child terms for the Issues.

On my index.php (http://aaron.ellissnyder.com/ttn/) I list links to all the issues (in the purple footer at the bottom of the page). When I click these links I get a 404 instead of directing to Taxonomy.php

How can I get it so when I navigate to http://aaron.ellissnyder.com/ttn/?taxonomy=Issue&term=issue-1 it takes me to the appropriate page?

Also, is there a way to make this work using permalinks?

Thanks so much for your help,
Aaron

Comment: Did you manually create the links at the bottom? If so can you add Taxonomy.php before the query string?

Comment: I did not manually create the links, I used wp_list_categories(). I'm not sure I follow what you're suggestion regarding Taxonomy.php is?

Comment: In your question you mentioned that it isn't going to Taxonomy.php instead you are being redirected to the 404 page, I figured if you had manually created the links, using some loop with a recordset, you could change the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks that your URLs are case-sensitive.
`http://aaron.ellissnyder.com/ttn/?taxonomy=Issue&term=issue-1` returns 404, whilst `http://aaron.ellissnyder.com/ttn/?Taxonomy=Issue&term=issue-1` does not.

`Past Issues` link in that purple footer works (...**T** axonomy...). The other three do not (...**t** axonomy).

Work on that and your problem will be solved.

Comment: This is a step in the right direction, but even though they don't return a 404 they are not going going to taxonomy.php or taxonomy-Issue.php. It seems like it is just going to index.php.

Comment: @user1114096 This link works: `http://aaron.ellissnyder.com/ttn/?taxonomy=issue&term=issue-1`. I don't know if it works as you intended, but it does not return 404. I'm not familiar with WordPress but I guess it processes URLs like every other CMS or framework - in case of unknown URL arguments it returns 404. Just work on the URLs' and controllers' compatibility.

Comment: THANK YOU. Although this isn't  a "fix" this is certainly what I needed to get in the right direction.  Issue should be issue (lowercase) -- now to get wp_listcategories outputting the right thing...